# Check If a coordinate exist in a table in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Below are my table schema and data.

```
#Table Structure 
CREATE TABLE public.route
(
  name text NOT NULL,
  startpoint point NOT NULL,
  endpoint point NOT NULL,
  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('route_id_seq'::regclass),
  CONSTRAINT route_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
 OIDS=FALSE
);

#Table Data
INSERT INTO public.route (name, startpoint, endpoint, id) VALUES ('Atlantic',     (-73.848838,40.688299), (-73.824869,40.694831), 1);
INSERT INTO public.route (name, startpoint, endpoint, id) VALUES ('Guy Brewer', (-73.7991,40.708257), (-73.78543,40.688334), 2);
```

want to check if column `startpoint` has a point `(-73.848838,40.688299)`  in `route` table

Comment: and what is problem ?

Comment: i need a query to check if  point `(-73.848838,40.688299)` exist in column `startpoint ` of the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM route
WHERE startpoint ~= POINT '(-73.848838,40.688299)';
```

You can speed this up with a GiST index:

```
CREATE INDEX ON route USING gist (startpoint);
```